# MS-Access, form that adds info to a one to many relationship

Tags: forms, ms-access, one-to-many

I have a access table with Orders and a sub-table with itemId's.
It has one to many relationship.

I want to create a form that adds itemId's to a selected order(already existing).

This is how i expect it to look like:

```
Order:        [            ]
ItemId:       [            ]
Measurement1: [            ]
Measurement2: [            ]

        [Save-button]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why not add a sub form and link the aster and child fields.  Then everything will be tied to gether properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subforms are the politically correct way to go IF you want users to have access to the order screen. If users do not need access to the order details directly, only to items, then you could put a combo-box for

```
 Order: [              [V]]
```

which has its control source as a query for your order ID in the orders table. Link that to your Orders field in the Item table and it will store the order as a subform would, without letting the user see details of the order.

However, if you want multiple items shown for a selected order, use subforms (having a subform which is multiple-item)

Comment: That's one option. I personally use forms which require the user to enter which Building and which Room an item is in; the form for the item is long (30 fields), so it's more space-saving for me to put a drop-down to select the Building and Room references (using some easy query sources) then fill in the rest of the info. In this way, the user cannot edit the pre-set Rooms and Buildings; only select from them.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [subforms](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-subforms-HP005188395.aspx). The Orders table will be for the main form and the items will be on the subform. Access does a good job of handling the OrderID key in the Items records.